# How to display login error and "fill all the fields" messages on the same page using php?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I am building a php login page where the user is required to put in a username and password for logging in.

My question is

- how can I display the 'invalid username or password' error message on the same page?
- how can I display the "Fill up all the fields" message when users leave the fields empty?

In the code below when I leave the fields empty the "fill up all the fields" message disappears quickly. When I type a wrong password or username same thing happens. How can I get those messages to stay on shown on the page when an error occur?

Code:

```
<?php
session_start();
$json = isset($_POST["admin"]) ? $_POST["admin"] : "";
if (!($admin = checkJson($json))) {
    print "Fill up all the fields";
    exit();
}
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL ^ MYSQLI_REPORT_INDEX);
try {
    $initials = parse_ini_file("../.ht.asetukset.ini");
    $connection = mysqli_connect($initials["databaseserver"], $initials["username"], $initials["password"], $initials["database"]);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    header("Location:../html/connectionError.html");
    exit();
}
// Tehdään sql-lause, jossa kysymysmerkeillä osoitetaan paikat
// joihin laitetaan muuttujien arvoja
$sql = "select * from admin where uname=? and paswd=SHA2(?, 256)";
try {
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($connection, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ss', $admin->uname, $admin->paswd);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    $print = mysqli_stmt_get_result($stmt);
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_object($print)) {
        $_SESSION["admin"] = "$row->uname";
        print $_SESSION["returnSite"];
        exit();
    } else
        print "Invalid username or password!";
    mysqli_close($connection);
    print "Login in...";
} catch (Exception $e) {
    print "Error!";
}
?>
<?php

function checkJson($json)
{
    if (empty($json)) {
        return false;
    }
    $admin = json_decode($json, false);
    if (empty($admin->uname) || empty($admin->paswd)
        ) {
        return false;
    }
    return $admin;
}
?>
```

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta name="author" content="">
<meta name="description"
    content="Team 14 project work. The website contains basic web development guides utilizing HTML5, CSS, JavaScript and Bootstrap">
<title>admin login</title>
<!--Link to bootstrap.-->
<link
    href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    rel="stylesheet"
    integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3"
    crossorigin="anonymous">

<!--Link to local css file.-->
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Dosis&display=swap"
    rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <!--navigation bar starts here.-->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="../html/index.html"
                    style="color: #0000ff; font-family: 'Dosis', sans-serif; font-size: 20px;"><b>CodeSchool</b></a>
                <div id="navbarNav">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active"
                            aria-current="page" href="../html/html.html">HTML Basics</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active"
                            href="../html/css.html">CSS Basics</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link active"
                            href="../html/js.html">JavaScript</a></li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <!--anchor link added.--> <a class="nav-link active" href="#a">About
                                Us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <!--anchor link added.--> <a class="nav-link active" href="#b">Contact
                                Us</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <!--anchor link added.--> <a class="nav-link active" href="../html/login.html">Log
                                In / Sign Up</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <!--navigation bar ends here.-->
    <main>
    <div class="box" style="background-color: #2f303a; color:white">
            <h1 class="padding"><b>Admin login Page</b></h1><br>
            <h1 class="padding"><b>Please provide your Administrator login credentials</b></h1><br>
        </div>
        <!--box with search bar ends here.-->
        <!--other content.-->
        <div class="sec1">
                <h1 class="padding"><b>Administrators Login</b></h1><br>
            
        <div class="sec">
        <!--box with search bar starts here.-->
        <form id='userForm'>
            <h3>Username:</h3>
            <input class='input' type='text' name='uname' value='' placeholder='Your username'><br>
            <h3>Password:</h3>
            <input class='input' type='password' name='paswd' value=''
                placeholder='Enter your password' id="myInput"><br>
            <p>
                Show Password<input type="checkbox" onclick="myFunction()">
            </p>
            <br> 
            <div class='cnt'>
            <input 
                style='font-size: 20px; background-color: #ff7a18; border-radius: 25px; width: 100px'
                type='button' name='submit' value='Login'
                onclick='sendInfo(this.form);'><br> <br></div>
        </form>
        <p id='result'></p>
        <p style='font-size:20px'> <a class="nav-link active" href="./login.html">To go back to users login page click here!</a> </p>
        <p style="font-size: 25px" id='result'></p>
        
        </div>
        </div>
    </main>
    <!--Footer starts here.-->
    <footer>
        <section class="mb-4" id="b">
            <!--Section heading-->
            <h2 class="h1-responsive font-weight-bold text-center my-4">Contact
                Us</h2>
            <!--Section description-->
            <p class="text-center w-responsive mx-auto mb-5">Do you have any
                questions? Please do not hesitate to contact us directly. Our team
                will come back to you within a matter of hours to help you.</p>
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-9 mb-md-0 mb-5">
                    <form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" action="mail.php"
                        method="POST">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="md-form mb-0">
                                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" class="form-control">
                                    <label for="name" class="">Your name</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <div class="md-form mb-0">
                                    <input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="form-control">
                                    <label for="email" class="">Your email</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="md-form mb-0">
                                    <input type="text" id="subject" name="subject"
                                        class="form-control"> <label for="subject" class="">Subject</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-12">
                                <div class="md-form">
                                    <textarea id="message" name="message" rows="2"
                                        class="form-control md-textarea"></textarea>
                                    <label for="message">Your message</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                    <div class="text-center text-md-left">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary"
                            onclick="document.getElementById('contact-form').submit();">Send</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="status"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 text-center">
                    <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
                        <li><i class="fas fa-map-marker-alt fa-2x"></i>
                            <p>Visamäentie 35 A, 13100 Hämeenlinna</p></li>
                        <li><i class="fas fa-phone mt-4 fa-2x"></i>
                            <p>(+358) 23456 789</p></li>
                        <li><i class="fas fa-envelope mt-4 fa-2x"></i>
                            <p>email@email.com</p></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="py-3 my-4">
                <ul class="nav justify-content-center border-bottom pb-3 mb-3">
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">Facebook</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">Instagram</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">LinkedIn</a></li>
                    <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link px-2 text-muted">Discord</a></li>
                </ul>
                <p class="text-center text-muted">&copy; 2022 HAMK, Team 14</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </footer>
    <!--Footer ends here.-->
    <script>
            function sendInfo(form){
                var admin=new Object();
                admin.uname=form.uname.value;
                admin.paswd=form.paswd.value;
                var jsonAdmin=JSON.stringify(admin);
                
                xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                  if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
                       document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 
                       this.responseText;
                       if (this.responseText=="Error"){
                            document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = 
                            "Username or/and password are wrong";
                       }
                       else{
                            window.location.assign("../php/admin.php");
                       }
                  }
                };
                xmlhttp.open("POST", "../php/admin_login.php", true);
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", 
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                xmlhttp.send("admin=" + jsonAdmin); 
            }
    </script>   
    <script>
            function myFunction() {
              var x = document.getElementById("myInput");
              if (x.type === "password") {
                x.type = "text";
              } else {
                x.type = "password";
              }
            }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's nothing in this code which would make any messages "disappear quickly"...are you doing some client-side redirecting or something? Please edit the question to provide a [mre] of the issue, which I suspect will include the HTML form and possibly some JavaScript as well as this PHP code. Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Why not check for all required fields using HTML (`<input required>`) or Javascript before sending the form?

Comment: Also, please don't roll your own password hashing functionality. Learn about PHP's built-in, up-to-date, secure [password hashing and verification functions](https://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php) instead.

Comment: `if (this.responseText=="Error"){` is never going to work, because your PHP prints all sorts of other stuff, never just the word "Error". If you want to detect this, consider instead returning a structured JSON response containing a status, and a message (or list of messages) to be displayed on screen, and then having some JavaScript which will place each part on the page appropriately in some HTML. That way you don't need to rely on brittle string matching in the raw response to detect validation errors.

Comment: Code smell: `xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); xmlhttp.send("admin=" + jsonAdmin); ` ... why are you sending form-url-encoded data with JSON wrapped inside it?? If you're going to send JSON, send just JSON with the correct content-type header, don't just push JSON inside form-encoded data. Or, since this is a simple payload with two values, just send a normal set of form data...JSON isn't really necessary in this scenario.

Answer (score -1):

use the session for displaying the message and unset it after display that variable so that, it is not come again

```
$_SESSION['message'] = "Invalid username or password!";


if($_SESSION['message']!=''){
   echo $_SESSION['message'];// display the message
   unset($_SESSION['message']);// unset the message, so it is not come again in same page
}
```